# How to upgrade rack to v3 for rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade, rack

How to upgrade the `rack` gem from v2 to v3 for rails 7?

If you try to use:

```
gem 'rack', '>= 3'
```

Bundle will show you the result of the upgrade:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    rack (>= 3)

    rails (~> 7.0.4) was resolved to 7.0.4, which depends on
      actionpack (= 7.0.4) was resolved to 7.0.4, which depends on
        rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.2.0)
```

Answer (score 8):

For the beginning of 2023 it's not possible to upgrade `rack` to v3 for `rails` v7.0 because it's not prepared yet. Please follow this PR to get the latest information on the ongoing process:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/46594
- https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/47052

Comment: It's here, available in rails `7.1.0.beta1` with no open issues for rack 3 in the [7.1.0 milestone](https://github.com/rails/rails/milestone/82). I'm using rack `3.0.8` and puma `6.3.1` on a new app. Check your dependencies, as I know [thin doesn't support rack 3](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/issues/389).

Answer (score 3):

This will become possible starting in Rails 7.1 according to this comment [from here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/46594#issuecomment-1621834052):

> The work to support Rack 3 has been done on the main branch, so it will be released as Rails 7.1